# Python3: Connection reset by peer while reading line from socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I get an `Connection reset by peer` error message while running this python3 script:

```
import struct, socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 64012

# read bytes from socket and return it as ascii representation
def read_line_from_socket(s): 
    buf= ""
    while True:
        byteData = s.recv(1)
        if byteData == b"\n":
            break
        buf += byteData.decode("ascii")
    return buf

def read_four_longs_for_addition(s):
    sum = 0
    counter = 1
    while counter <= 4:
        sum += struct.unpack("I", s.recv(4))[0]
        counter += 1 # python does not support ++, += 1 has to be used
    print(sum) # sum overflows int (number > 32 bit)
    return sum

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST,PORT))
    print(read_line_from_socket(s))
    print(read_line_from_socket(s))
    s.send(struct.pack("l", read_four_longs_for_addition(s)))
    # print(s.recv(32)) # receives "You have succes..", NOT resulting in an Connection reset by peer which indicates success
    print(read_line_from_socket(s)) # results in "Connection reset by peer"
    s.close()
```

The code on the server which is communicating with my client socket looks like this:

```
#define BANNER \
  "Welcome to " LEVELNAME ", brought to you by https://exploit.education"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int i;
  unsigned long quad[sizeof(long)], result, wanted;

  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  printf("%s\nFor this level, sizeof(long) == %d, keep that in mind :)\n",
      BANNER, (int)sizeof(long));

  if (getrandom((void *)&quad, sizeof(quad), 0) != sizeof(quad)) {
    errx(1, "unable to getrandom(%d bytes)", sizeof(quad));
  }

  result = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(long); i++) {
    result += quad[i];
    if (write(1, (void *)&quad[i], sizeof(long)) != sizeof(long)) {
      errx(1, "Why have you foresaken me, write()");
    }
  }

  if (read(0, (void *)&wanted, sizeof(long)) != sizeof(long)) {
    errx(1, "Unable to read\n");
  }

  if (result == wanted) {
    printf("You have successfully passed this level, well done!\n");
  } else {
    printf("Whoops, better luck next time. Receieved %lu, wanted %lu\n", wanted,
        result);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Expected behavior:

After successfully sending the correct sum of the received long values my script reads the last line "You have successfully passed this level, well done!\n" until the `"\n"` new line, prints it out to the screen and finally closing the socket connection.

Actual output:

```
Welcome to phoenix/net-two, brought to you by https://exploit.education
For this level, sizeof(long) == 4, keep that in mind :)
9057758327
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "net-2.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(read_line_from_socket(s))
  File "net-2.py", line 10, in read_line_from_socket
    byteData = s.recv(1)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Looking at the process with `strace python3 nameOfPythonScript.py`, I can't see any problem and everything should be working fine:

```
recvfrom(3, "n", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)      = 1
recvfrom(3, "e", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)      = 1
recvfrom(3, "!", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)      = 1
recvfrom(3, "\n", 1, 0, NULL, NULL)     = 1
write(1, "You have successfully passed thi"..., 52You have successfully passed this level, well done!
) = 52
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7ffff7bcd0c0}, {sa_handler=0x5555557d8980, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7ffff7bcd0c0}, 8) = 0
munmap(0x7ffff6c0e000, 262144)          = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

My question:

Why does the Connection reset occur? Does it have to do with the `return 0;` in the server program code? Note that if I `recv` a fixed number of bytes instead of trying to read the complete last line the error does not occur (see comments in my script's code)